# autoincrementar sqlite administrator para java

Tags: java, netbeans, sqlite

Estoy estudiando la creacion de una mini base de datos en lenguaje Java, mediante la ayuda del programa "SQLiteAdministrator". La cuestion es: he creado una columna que controla los ID de usuario (el cual tiene funcion de autoincremento) pero, en el momento que se elimina un usuario, me gustaria que en el siguiente usuario que se cree, se tenga en cuenta que hay un vacio por ocupar. No se como explicarlo bien, acompaño esta duda con dos imagenes. Gracias de antemano.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No hay id 16 ¿Cuál es el problema? o en caso contrario ¿En qué beneficia al usuario/aplicación?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*No es una buena práctica eliminar registros de usuarios de la base de datos. Esto podría traerte problemas mas adelante.*

> **Ejemplo:** Si tu quieres que tu app web le permita a los usuarios eliminar su cuenta. Tu no eliminas su registro, pero si le permites desactivar su usuario

Entonces, para empleados debes agragar una nueva columna que se llame por ejemplo: estado(int) y que además tenga como valor personalizado 0.

```
ALTER TABLE `empleados` ADD `estado` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `Correo`;
```

**¿De qué te sirve el valor personalizado 0?**

> 0 va a tener el valor de activado.
> 1 va a tener el valor de desactivado

**¿Cómo usarías esto mas adelante?**

> **Ejemplo:** Vas a llamar solo a los usuarios que estén activos, es decir, que tengan el valor 0

```
$sql "SELECT * FROM clientes Where 'estado' = 0 ";
```

Comment: No , quise decir "registros de usuarios". En mi experiencia, eliminar los registros de los usuario se convirtió en un problema a largo plazo. Quizás habrán excepciones y al final cada quien determina el funcionamiento de su aplicación. Pero con lo poco que sé no lo recomendaría. O no por lo menos, en primer plano.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo; es el contexto que le falta(ba) a tu respuesta. Los absolutos tipo todo-nada, siempre-nunca son de cuidado.

Comment: efectue lo que comentaste y quedo solventado. Gracias @LilibethQ